# Carousel in watchOS

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I would like to do a sort of carousel within an Apple Watch app where cards still scroll vertically, however when not on screen they are sort of in the background in a sense.

This would involve shrinking groups and their content based on their position and probably overriding any WatchKit layout features.

Is this possible in WatchKit or will I have to jump over to SpriteKit to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

With watchOS 6 and Apple's new SwiftUI framework, you can now do this by creating a [list](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) with the carousel list style.

This fits your description where visually one element is in focus while the others are in the background.